# How to properly get a numpy array in the correct shape from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to take data from across a `pandas` dataframe and turn it into a `numpy array`.  The gist is to take a column and turn it into an array with six lagged values *with* the ability to add features so the array looks like the following for each row of data:

`array([lag1 value,  lag1 feature 1,  lag1 feature 2], [lag2 value,  lag2 feature 1,  lag2 feature 2], [lag3 value,  lag3 feature 1,  lag3 feature 2],[lag4 value,  lag4 feature 1,  lag4 feature 2], [lag5 value,  lag5 feature 1,  lag5 feature 2], [lag6 value,  lag6 feature 1,  lag6 feature 2]])`

I believe the end shape should be `(37, 6, 3)` for 37 rows of data, 6 arrays of lag values with each of those six arrays containing 3 features.

I have been successful in getting the lag values to work but not the features.  Example data is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ord_qty = [2900, 10504, 11997, 10824, 12799, 12734, 13940, 15188, 17323, 9930, 15682, 14835, 13870, 13601, 14654, 16501, 18221, 17139, 17182, 12509, 11483, 11073,
17069, 16186, 15687, 16978, 16642, 14837, 17693, 17194, 18204, 19391, 20475, 19849, 21052, 18003, 16186, 19320, 15650, 26697, 14503, 15517, 17956, 20283, 20056,
20128, 19795, 16468, 15349, 15416, 16114, 16669, 17139, 15082]
promotion = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
ma3 = [8467.0, 8467.0, 8467.0, 11108.333333333334, 11873.333333333334, 12119.0, 13157.666666666666, 13954.0, 15483.666666666666, 14147.0, 14311.666666666666,
13482.333333333334, 14795.666666666666, 14102.0, 14041.666666666666, 14918.666666666666, 16458.666666666668, 17287.0, 17514.0, 15610.0, 13724.666666666666,
11688.333333333334, 13208.333333333334, 14776.0, 16314.0, 16283.666666666666, 16435.666666666668, 16152.333333333334, 16390.666666666668, 16574.666666666668,
17697.0, 18263.0, 19356.666666666668, 19905.0, 20458.666666666668, 19634.666666666668, 18413.666666666668, 17836.333333333332, 17052.0, 20555.666666666668,
18950.0, 18905.666666666668, 15992.0, 17918.666666666668, 19431.666666666668, 20155.666666666668, 19993.0, 18797.0, 17204.0, 15744.333333333334,
15626.333333333334, 16066.333333333334, 16640.666666666668, 16296.666666666666]

samp_dict = {'ord_qty':ord_qty, 'promo':promotion, 'ma3':ma3}
samp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(samp_dict)
samp_df
```

I have successfully used the following code to get the lagged values (in this case 'ord_qty') in the correct shape.  How would I add additional features?

```
lags = 6
horizon = 12
###############Make a multi-output time series dataset#####################
series = samp_df['ord_qty']
#number of lags in the input
Tx = lags
#number of steps in the output 
Ty = horizon
#instantiate list to take in the train (X) and test(Y) data set
X = []
Y = []
# run a series from 0 to the length of the dataframe minus the horizon to create a "step through time" data set
for t in range(len(series) - Tx - Ty + 1):
    x = series[t:t+Tx]
    X.append(x)
    y = series[t+Tx:t+Tx+Ty]
    Y.append(y)
#reshape into numpy arrays for faster processing in ML models
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, Tx)
Y = np.array(Y).reshape(-1, Ty)
```

This is how I tried to solve my issue (amongst variations of the above):

```
lags = 6
horizon = 12
###############Make a multi-output time series dataset#####################
series = samp_df['ord_qty']
feature1 = samp_df['ma3']
feature2 = samp_df['promo']
#number of lags in the input
Tx = lags
#number of steps in the output 
Ty = horizon
#instantiate list to take in the train (X) and test(Y) data set
X = []
Y = []
# run a series from 0 to the length of the dataframe minus the horizon to create a "step through time" data set
for t in range(len(series) - Tx - Ty + 1):
    x0 = series[t:t+Tx]
    x0 = np.array(x0).reshape(Tx, 1)
    x1 = feature1[t:t+Tx]
    x1 = np.array(x1).reshape(Tx,1)
    x2 = feature2[t:t+Tx]
    x2 = np.array(x2).reshape(Tx,1)
    x = np.hstack([x0, x1, x2])
    X.append(x)
    y = series[t+Tx:t+Tx+Ty]
    Y.append(y)
# #reshape into numpy arrays for faster processing in ML models
X = np.array(X).reshape(37, Tx, 3)
Y = np.array(Y).reshape(-1, Ty)
```

Comment: `samp_df['ord_qty']` is a series.  `samp_df['ord_qty'].to_numpy()` is the array derived from it.  So the rest of your code is collecting slices of several arrays, and reorganizing them.  So what's the problem or error?  Overall the question is wordy without a clear focus.